# HPLIP: "hp-setup -i" won't ask to setup plugin for HP LaserJet Pro MFP M428fdw

Tags: drivers, printing, scanner, versions, hplip

I'm trying to add a HP LaserJet Pro MFP M428fdw printer/scanner to a few Ubuntu 16.04 PCs, they all have HPLIP ver 3.20.0 which is higher than the compatible version for this printer model. When running hp-setup -i, after selecting the network printer and confirming the ppd file is correct it would normally ask for the plugin for the scanner side of the printer to be installed, however this does not appear and it only lets you add it as a printer. Is there anything I might be missing or is there an alternative way to set this up?

Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate the Ubuntu version number

Answer (score 0):

You need to install some Python 3 packages:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5 python3-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5 python3-notify python3-reportlab
```

Then when you run hplip…….run

```
sh hplip-3.20.9.run
```

answer the install dependencies with a ‘no’

You need to do this too:

```
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module
```

Now delete your printer and reinstall. It should work.

Comment: odd procedure - what's the explanation?

Comment: Hplip has dependencies on python. For a reason I don't understand, it will use python3 if available and old python is absent. Worked for me.